# How to use the swagger-ui npm module with an existing OpenAPI specification file

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Looking at [the documentation for installing Swagger-UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/HEAD/docs/usage/installation.md) one can see that two official `npm` modules are being published: `swagger-ui` and `swagger-ui-dist`. However, I really struggle to figure out how these are supposed to be used with an already existing [OpenApi 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md) specification.

The only thing I need is a simple web application (plain `node.js` or `express.js` or whatever works) which will serve my existing `specification.yml` document embedded into the plain Swagger-UI files on a path like `/docs`.

Since this needs to be done in a repeatable manner (will run in a Docker container in the end), manual editing of files is not desired in the process.

The closest I could get was downloading [a release tar ball](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases), extracting the `dist` folder, use tools like `sed` to replace the default specification file with my own one and finally host this on a webserver like `nginx`.

However, this looks unnecessary complex to me and makes me wonder what the `npm` modules are supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found two approaches to achieve my goal as outlined in the question.

#### Using unpkg

[unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) is an automated [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for all modules that are published on the `npm` registry. It allows to include and use any `npm` module in a static HTML file without any complex package managers, dependency resolvers etc.  This is especially great if you don't have any other need to use the `npm` ecosystem directly.

For `swagger-ui`, such an HTML file would look like this. Note that we are importing the `swagger-ui-dist` package which already includes all necessary dependencies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Inspired by https://gist.github.com/buzztaiki/e243ccc3203f96777e2e8141d4993664-->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css" >
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        // Swagger-ui configuration goes here.
        // See further: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md
        SwaggerUIBundle({
          deepLinking: true,
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          showExtensions: true,
          showCommonExtensions: true,
          url: specification.json // <-- adjust this to your webserver's structure
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Host this HTML file on your webserver and your all settled.

#### Using browserify / webpack

[browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) are module bundlers from the `npm` ecosystem that can collect an `npm` module and all its dependencies, then bundle them up in one single `js` file. This file can then be loaded and used in an HTML page.

While both tools might differ feature-wise in the details, for this job both of them work almost in the same way. The following example uses `browserify`, however, the general approach with `webpack` is the same.

First, install `browserify` globally:

`npm install -g browserify`

Then, install the `swagger-ui` module locally in your current folder:

`npm install --save swagger-ui`

Finally, bundle the `swagger-ui` module and all of its dependencies into a single output file:

`browserify --require swagger-ui -o bundle.js`

The according HTML page to include it could look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css">
        <title>Swagger-UI</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        // Swagger-ui configuration goes here.
        // See further: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md
        SwaggerUI({
          deepLinking: true,
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          showExtensions: true,
          showCommonExtensions: true,
          url: specification.json // <-- adjust this to your webserver's structure
        });
      };
    </script>
</html>
```

This approach might be preferred if you are using `browserify` or `webpack` within your ecosystem for other tasks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for whatever works the easiest solution will be to use an existing swagger-ui like the demo store and pass your spec in the url param:

http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/4411/7.json

If you want more of a standalone solution copy the swagger-ui dist directory to your deployment:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

then tweak the index.html to suit your needs